# Period of function $x\mapsto (f(x))^2$

Tags: periodic-functions

If i know, that $f(x)$ is a periodic function with period $T$, how should i prove, that $(f(x))^2$ has period $T_1 : T_1 \le T$.

I tried to use periodic function determination: $f(x)=f(x+T)$, but it wont help.

Comment: what do mean by $f^2$, the square of $f(x)$ or, $f$ composed with itself?

Comment: The square of $f(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then it is obvious, because $f^2(x+T)=\{f(x+T)\}^2=\{f(x)\}^2=f^2(x)$. Hence $f^2$ repeats itself after every interval of length $T$. Thus the period of $f^2$ divides $T$. Hence $T_1\leq T$.

Comment: I think you wanted to say "Hence $f^2\cdots$".

Comment: What do you mean with $a$ divides $b$ in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @GitGud Sorry for using the word "divides", I only meant $T=mT_1$ for some integer $m\geq1$.

Comment: Thanks @SamratMukhopadhyay for making the required edit.

Comment: If $f^2$ repeats itself after every interval of length $T$, then $T$ is it's period by the definition. How can i prove, that there is period $T_1$ which "divides" $T$?

Comment: @VladislavBrylinskiy Just set $T_1=T$ to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but i do not understand, how can i prove that $T_1$ can be smaller than $T$? Thank you for answers.

Comment: The period of a function is the smallest such interval after which the function repeats itself. Suppose $T_1$ is the period of the function and we know that the function repeats itself after every interval of length $T$, then we claim that $T=mT_1$ for some integer $m\geq 1$. This is because there exists $m_0$ such that $m_0T_1\leq T< (m_0+1)T_1$. Then either $T=m_0T_1$, or $f$ repeats after every interval of length $T-m_0T_1<T_1$, which the minimality of $T_1$.

Comment: Vladislav: You don't know that $T_1$ necessarily _is_ smaller than $T$, but you know that it's no greater (since $T$ is 'a' period of $f^2$, the least period is $T$ or less).  To show that $T_1$ _can be_ less than $T$, all you need to do is find an example.  For a simple one, try $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Comment: One thing to be a little careful about is talking about "the" period of a periodic function as the *smallest* interval of repetition.  What if $f$ only takes the two values $\pm1$?  What is "the" period of $f^2$?